# changing acm reference format section city, state, country as well as what is article 4?

Tags: formatting, citing, templates, document-classes, acm

I am using the acm conference format template (sample-sigconf.tex) found [here](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template).

My first question is in regards to the "ACM Reference Format" section that is automatically generated on the first page.

I have updated the conference location and it appears correctly under the copy right section, but the location under the reference format section does not match.  Searching through the template files I was able to find location being used (New York, NY) in acmart.cls.

Am I expected to make changes in this template file or is there a command that I should be using within my main tex file?  If neither of these are correct, am I supposed to simply keep it to New York, NY for reasons related to properly citing ACM conference papers?  It doesn't seem right that I would need to modify the cls file.

My second question is in regards to the tag "acmArticle".  I've noticed that it is set automatically to `\acmArticle{4}` and that `Article 4` is included in the same ACM reference format section.  This doesn't seem right to me.  What does this command do besides add to the reference section and can/should it be removed?

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @Alessandro Cuttin You want me to copy and paste the template file as well as the supporting bst and cls files I linked to here?  They're a bit long.  My question is regards to the template and supporting cls file.  I want to change what appears in the ACM Reference Format Section.  I've figured out how to do it, but it involves modifying the cls file.  This to me doesn't seem correct.  I was able to make the needed change by ctrl f -> "NY" which takes me to the correct location in the cls.  I then can change the location as I want.  Shouldn't there be a way to do this in the template?

Comment: My second question is in regards to the "\acmArticle{4}" command.  I including this here rather in a second post since both questions pertain to the ACM Reference Format section.  I'm wondering if this has any effect other than adding text to the ACM Reference Format section

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not change anything in the class. If you read the documentation for the class it states that `\acmArticle` (and other similar macros) are inserted by the editor(s) of the final volume, so you don't need to worry about that. The "ACM, New York" text should not be changed, because that's the publisher and place of publication for ACM published books. It doesn't depend on the conference location which is set using the `\acmConference` macro.